# Is the secret flag `chrome://flags` a legit trick or scam?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I've been seeing these "secret flags" (e.g. `chrome://flags/#max-tiles-for-interest-area`) for Chrome browser on Android posted all over the internet.

Are these legitimate tricks, or scams to phish users?

Answer (score 3):

Chrome flags (accessed by going to `chrome://flags` on Chrome) are basically on/off switches for experimental and dangerous (hence the warning at the top of the flags page) features not yet officially announced in a Chrome release.

They are most definitely not scams, but are experiments intended for testing by developers and beta testers of Chrome.